# How to drop marker clusters one by one after a specific interval of time?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have written the following code to display multiple markers in google map and i succeeded in it.Now i want to have a drop animation applied to markers and want to drop marker after a specific interval of time.I know i want to call `setTimeout` method ,but don't know where to call this method to achieve the result

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){ 
        if(markers.length>0){                
            var mapOptions={                 
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng),                
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP        
            };
            var infoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"),mapOptions);
            var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++){

                var imageIcon=i+1;               
                var data=markers[i];
                var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,data.lng);

                var marker=new google.maps.Marker({                    
                           position:latlng,
                           map:map,
                           title:data.title,
                           icon:"Icon/marker"+imageIcon+".PNG",
                           animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP                                     
                });                   

                bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                (function(marker,data){
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(e){
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
                         if(marker.getAnimation()!=null){
                            marker.setAnimation(null);
                         }else{
                            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                         }
                    });                
                })(marker,data);                            
            } //for loop ends here
           map.fitBounds(bounds);
           map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());             

        }//if condition check for marker.length ends here
    } //windows.load function ends here       
</script>
```

Comment: can you please paste your entire code including html..?

Comment: We don't really need the HTML here. The question is clear enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using setInterval. I don't think setTimeout would work here. See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/PWsVH/

```
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() { 

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        ...
    });

    i++;

    if(i >= coords.length) clearInterval(interval);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am getting the drop animation correctly.I have written `map.fitBounds(bounds)` and `map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter())` to display all the markers with out zooming out.The problem is called the above function after the `setInterval` function map i not getting displayed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you expecting the map to adjust after each marker is dropped? Or before the animation? After? Please clarify.

Comment: Ideally what i want is the map to adjust for all the markers intially and then have a rain of markers.If it is difficult to implement i would want the way you suggested ie the map to adjust after each marker is dropped.

Comment: See my next fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/JBvLA/ As you can see, the map is loaded with a zoom of 12 and a position that is not where our markers are. Then the setBounds function centers the map on the markers and adapts the zoom level. Of course you want to do that BEFORE your animation starts. Just comment the setBounds call to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried to implement the code you have given but i am getting error as  too much recursion in firefox

Comment: Are you sure you called the function at the right place? Give us a link to your map or paste your whole code here or in a fiddle. The code I provided should work. How many markers are you trying to display?

Comment: Thankyou very much for your wonderful answer.I was wrong, made few changes and the code is working perfectly...